# How to keep trailing zeros in csv using php fputcsv?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am using fputcsv function to write data in a file.But it is removing the trailing zeros from the output. Here is the code I am using

```
foreach($invoice_hdr_array as $csv_response) 
{
    fputcsv($fh1, $csv_response, ',', '"');  
}
```

If you observe the end of the line it should be 0.00. But I am getting as only 0.
In out put I am getting like this
`LIN,1,1234567890123,EN,,,1.00,94.00,94.00,0`

But this should be like below

`LIN,1,1234567890123,EN,,,1.00,94.00,94.00,0.00`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I test your input, and leave numbers as numbers, I get:

```
LIN,1,1234567890123,EN,,,1,94,94,0
```

Observe how all whole numbers loose their zero's, which is not what you get. Your question seems inaccurate? The only reason, I can think of, why you get `94.00`, is when it is a string. To illustrate this point I created this code:

```
$array = ['LIN', 1,1234567890123, 'EN', '', '', 1.00, '94.00', 94.00, '0.00'];
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $array);
fclose($out);
```

And the output is:

```
LIN,1,1234567890123,EN,,,1,94.00,94,0.00
```

So I see 2 solutions:

1. Make numbers with trailing zero's into strings.
2. Don't use `fputcsv()`, but make your own version.

And finally, do I need to point out that `0` is, numerically, the same as `0.00`?

Comment: Thank you, but the other side system will read this csv file. The last one is taxt rate. So they were asking tax rate as always 0.00.

Comment: @user3408779 Well, then make it into a string. See: [number_format($taxRate, 2);](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format). Do note that some tax rates may have more than 2 decimals. You might want to take that into account.

Comment: @user3408779 Nice to hear it is solved.